# mysqlpump parallelism and errors with foreign constraints

Tags: mysql, mysql-backup

I'm current on MySQL 5.7.26, and am trying to `mysqlpump` to take dumps of my database. I have successfully used `mysqldump` previously.

Doing the `mysqlpump` and piping that to a slave instance results in the following error:

> ERROR 1215 (HY000) at line 139: Cannot add foreign key constraint

I have found that if I turn off parallelism, then this particular problem goes away, but then I get another error

> ERROR 1822 (HY000) at line 141: Failed to add the foreign key
>   constaint. Missing index for constraint 'fb_profile_ibfk_1' in the
>   referenced table 'user'

I should also add that right now I'm testing with a database with all empty tables.

The problem certainly could be my schema. But this database has been in existence for a while and the `mysqldump`s were working fine.

The SQL to create the tables are below. Originally, the `user` table had `fb_id` defined as `fb_id VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE KEY DEFAULT NULL` but the version below was to see if allowing NULL in one table and non-NULL in another made a difference.

Also note this causes the 1822 error. I need find a reduced table set that generates the 1215.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
    user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    fb_id VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE KEY
) AUTO_INCREMENT=1001;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fb_profile(
    fb_id VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (fb_id) REFERENCES user(fb_id)
)
```

and the database was created with this

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS db 
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
    DEFAULT COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Are there any known issues around `mysqlpump` and foreign keys?

Comment: This sounds like a bug in `mysqlpump`. If the foreign keys are valid in the original tables, it should copy them properly.

Comment: It seems like it may be loading definitions in the wrong order -- it's trying to add the foreign key to `fb_profile` before it adds the unique key to `user`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll post to MysQL forums to see if this is a known issue or if I'm doing something wrong in my SQL. For the 1215, it definitely seemed to be doing thing in the wrong order since. The user is the table that is the foreign key in other tables. And after the 1215 if I `SHOW TABLES;`, the user table does not exist. So there does seem to be an order issue.

Comment: Why have you created a separate tag for `mysqlpump`?